# Is there a non-combative term for the word "enemy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am a veteran of the wars in Iraq and Afghanistan. When talking about the people opposing us, I have always referred to them as the "enemy." Now, as I get a little older, and a little more aware (specifically, as I became a determinist), I have lost any hostility I feel towards them, and I feel that calling them the "enemy" demonizes them in a way I no longer wish to do. So, I was hoping there was some neutral term applied to enemy combatants, even if it's historical or in another language. I think opponent comes close, but it's not quite there. I was hoping there was a word like "interlocutor" meant for combatants of war.

I have checked the [OED (paywall, I think, I get it through my library)](https://www-oed-com.denverlibrary.idm.oclc.org/view/th/class/137933), and the words I think that come closest are two obsolete words "contrary" and "adverse." (obviously those words are still in use today, just not in the noun sense of a contrary or adverse being someone who opposes you). Does anyone else have any better matches?

One note, some may suggest I call them by the name they go by, such as the Taliban. The problem is that the Taliban is one of dozens of different groups of fighters and we rarely knew who belonged to which. So, I was hoping for a neutral term I could apply to all of them.

Comment: While not completely neutral, *foe* might be a reasonable substitute. It's a bit less freighted, I think

Comment: You used the word *fighter*; *combatant* is a synonym. *Adversary*? What do feel is not quite right about *opponent*?

Comment: *Competitor* would be reasonably neutral.

Comment: I think the grammatically apt version of your *adverse* would be *adversary.* Try looking that one up.

Comment: Is adversary too combative? It's often used formally, e.g. https://www.army.mil/about/

Comment: I fail to see how enemy demonize someone. Enemy does not convey that sense.

Comment: Could you please explain how determinism would require you to avoid a non-combative word for someone either you are attacking or is attacking you?  Or are you saying that a determinist point of view entails that you must also be a pacifist?

Comment: @Tuffy Determinism has simply allowed me to let go of all my hatred towards these people. If everyone is doing the only thing they can, why should I be angry? And, I am not a pacifist.

Comment: The problem with "fighters" is that it is so neutral it can be applied to both sides at the same time. I was looking for something like "counterparty" as suggested in the top answer below.

Comment: As for how "enemy" demonizes people, imagine you are having a debate with someone, and you call them your "enemy". Don't you believe that sets up an unduly hostile conversation? I do. And, I believe Afghans hearing me calling the enemy combatants "enemies" would take this rather negatively.

Comment: Is there a reason "combatant" that you use doesn't fit?

Comment: lol at a self described determinist choosing to use a different word

Comment: @eps I never WANTED to WANT to change my vocabulary, I just do, entirely outside my realm of control. The only 2 reasons to ever consciously do anything is because you are forced or you want to. But we don't control our wants. I can't choose to want to change my vocabulary, this just simply happens outside of my control. My biology mixed with my environment to make me want to change my vocab, entirely outside of my control.

Comment: You will never get around the fact that the people you are fighting are people who you are figting. Personaly "enemy" does not demonise people, in my own interpretation The problem is that you may well demonise people who you are fighting - regardless of what word you use. For American soliders after the first world war - the word "japanese" could carry many rather negative connotations.

Comment: "Friend" in some contexts means the opposite

Comment: @fev - on second thought, perhaps it was. You can put it back in if you wish to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was saying in a comment I would suggest **Counterparty**. It's different from Counterpart as suggested in another example because it has slightly different connotations in daily usage. It does denote another *group* of people who are taking an opposing side and not just a single person. It's not explicitly hostile either. It's simply a group who exists by necessity due to a position being taken.

It also has french roots in [countre part](https://www.etymonline.com/word/counterpart).

> mid-15c., countre part "duplicate of a legal document," from French contrepartie, from contre "facing, opposite" (see contra (prep., adv.)) + partie "copy of a person or thing," originally fem. past participle of partir "to divide" (see party (n.)).

Comment: Counterparty [means](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/counterparty) "the other person or institution entering into a financial contract or transaction". It's not an appropriate word here.

Comment: Did you not [look up the definition of counterparty](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+counterparty)?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Sorry, but my referent isn't a dictionary.

Comment: @user2357112 That is only one sense of the word.

Comment: @SetofTheseus: It's the only sense of the word I can find in any dictionary, and the only way the word is used in the first 10 pages of Google search results for `counterparty`. "Sorry, but my referent isn't a dictionary" - what *is* your referent, then? It must be incredibly obscure, and probably a typo.

Comment: (And while we're at it, "referent" probably isn't the word you're looking for either.)

Comment: An obsolete definition of counterparty in the OED says "an opposite party in a law-suit or contest; an adversary or opponent", and while the current usage is about parties in a transaction, it is not a stretch to use this for parties of war. And, since language is constantly evolving, I don't have a problem trying to resurrect this obsolete definition, if it is the  best fit, and so far, this sounds the most neutral to me.

Comment: @JimmyG.: If people need to get past the OED's hundred-dollar subscription paywall to access a single obsolete definition that sort of agrees with your usage, they're not going to find it. You're basically making up your own definitions at that point, as far as intelligibility goes.

Comment: IMHO this should not be the chosen answer. As user2357112 stated that this was not really a combat/war related term. It just does not fit the meaning of the former enemy of war.

Comment: I agree that I don't like this answer, but it's up to the OP to decide what works for them. Future readers can draw their own conclusions if the accepted answer has 2 votes and there are alternative answers with 40+ votes ...

Comment: @BenBolker: Indeed it’s up to the OP can decide, but we can urge them to reconsider if it seems they’re making a mistake.  There are several excellent suggestions in other answers which could all reasonably suit OP’s described aims — but this answer is simply wrong.

Comment: To put the claims to rest that no one uses counterparty within the context of war and the different parties in war either at all or in modern times. I will provide quickly gathered usages of it from twitter in exactly this context https://twitter.com/nbrockway1/status/1612667413761228800 

https://twitter.com/iamzheanna/status/1640727809013293056

https://twitter.com/elvisking1977/status/1629661512167231488

https://twitter.com/w_t_payne/status/1637707315494232066

Comment: For those without twitter access or opposed to using it here are images (I will also post text versions)

https://imgur.com/ZnS19MT.png https://imgur.com/ktmFAvY.png https://imgur.com/5q8BF75.png https://imgur.com/ATN2vse.png

Comment: "Can't have peace negotiations w a counterparty that commits war crimes and wants to bomb civilians into submission."  

"For what? The audacity to critique open risk associated with a global imperialist counterparty in proxy war with my own country, having a backdoor in content delivery to 65% of US youth. I engaged in good faith, conceded mistakes, and amended views as new ideas were presented."

Comment: "Wrong.  "Western military capacity" is not static, and in fact gets stronger with use.  Even a proxy war with Russia (US as part of a NATO counterparty) as is being played out will deter China (provided UKR is victorious)."

"There cannot be any negotiations until Russia puts forward a credible counterparty. A serial liar and war criminal is not a serious proposition. Just a joke in bad taste.

When Russia is ready to negotiate, they can demonstrate it by choosing a serious leader who has credibility."

Comment: @user2357112 an expensive database does not need to be accessed. This term is used as I said in the manner I said. It's just not captured in the *more* prevalent usage by free dictionaries or top 10 blogspam results from Google!

Comment: @SetofTheseus — Your *counterparty* examples appear to refer to parties in (would-be) negotiations — not a war opponents.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Negotiations between who and in regards to what? I'll answer for you since I don't think you're reading it charitably. (would-be) Negotiations between the two parties engaged in war and (would-be) negotiations in regards to said war. 

Also it's used in the second example without regards to negotiations between the parties. It's talking about one party to the war and a counterparty in the same war.

Answer (score 56):

If you referred to the various groups as [**adversaries**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adversary), you would imply nothing of the unity or justice of their causes; simply that their aims were opposed to your own, in a particular contest, conflict, or debate.

Comment: Air Force general Curtis LeMay supposedly said, "The Soviets are our adversaries; our enemy is the Navy."

Comment: There are multiple options here and I upvoted more than one, but I think this is by far the best

Comment: JFK in most of his speeches systemally used "adversary".

Answer (score 51):

I would say, "***opponent***" as it sounds less combative.

> a person who is on an opposing side in a game, contest, controversy, or the like; adversary.
> [[Dictionary.com]](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/opponent)

Comment: Opponent is someone you oppose: I don't think this is as neutral as the OP wishes.

Comment: @Greybeard oppose has multiple meanings. It can mean to disagree with someone but also literally to be on the other (opposite) side. For example if someone sits opposite of me at a table that person literally opposes me. This says nothing about how I feel about that person. But yeah, the ambiguity doesn't make the neutrality clear.

Comment: @greybeard but you are opposing them, you just don't feel they are morally wrong, just on the other side. Exactly how you would feel in a game

Comment: OP did literally ask “When talking about the people **opposing us**…”.

Comment: This was my first thought as well. @Greybeard Do you usually feel hostility towards the other player(s) in a game?

Comment: My first reaction to *'opponent'* was that it is far from the 'neutral' descriptor the OP wants.  The primary definition offered by the OED seems to think so too - *A person who stands in conflict or disagreement with another, esp. in a fight, argument, or legal dispute; an antagonist or adversary. Also (in a contest, race, game, etc.): a person who is in competition with another; a member of the opposite side or team.*

Answer (score 46):

It's not a single word, but it is very neutral. You could just call them ***the other side***.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/side) definition nr 14 for ***side*** says:

> COUNTABLE NOUN B2
> ***The different sides in a war***, argument, or negotiation are the groups of people who are opposing each other.
>
> - Both sides appealed for a new ceasefire.

Here are some examples of such a use:

> In view of the fact that the Secretary General has again made an appeal for a unilateral cease fire, which he has repeatedly said would be applied only if ***the other side*** did not fire on United States forces... ([House of Commons Debates, Official Report,](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Rmf-Oa-cxY4C&q=%22the%20other%20side%20did%20not%20fire%22&dq=%22the%20other%20side%20did%20not%20fire%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNrs_ziPH_AhWUNcAKHczEBt8Q6AF6BAgFEAI) Canada. Parliament. House of Commons · 1967)

> At our request they had agreed to maintain the truce - provided that ***the other side*** did not fire first- and the bombing pause so long as Mr Kosygin and I were meeting. (*[A Personal Record: The Labour Government](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=249AAAAAIAAJ&q=%22the%20other%20side%20did%20not%20fire%22&dq=%22the%20other%20side%20did%20not%20fire%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNrs_ziPH_AhWUNcAKHczEBt8Q6AF6BAgGEAI)*, 1964-1970, Sir Harold Wilson, 1971)

Comment: A good single word for "the other side" would be counterparty.

Comment: @SetofTheseus True, but still "counter" does have something opposing. I think "the other side" is as neutral as you can get...

Comment: @fev I don't know if I fully agree. As a "counterpart" is simply someone who would mirror my same functions in another company. The counter isn't really meant to mean "aggression towards each other" but a mirroring of function. The etymology of the word is that it comes from this type of meaning. Duplication. countre (french)

Comment: "The other side" is actually what I have been calling them. But I really like "counterparty" suggested by @SetofTheseus .

Comment: @SetofTheseus you should do your own answer with counterparty. I will accept that answer.

Comment: Uh, yeah but no. Did you [look up *counterparty* in the dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22counterparty)?

Comment: @JimmyG. Done here https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609579/482946

Answer (score 22):

After reflecting on this a bit — your identification as a *determinist* and the term *opponent* not being neutral enough — I will offer:

> **counterpart**
>  a person or thing holding a position or performing a function that corresponds to that of another person or thing in
> another place.
>  <sub>“the minister held talks with his French
> counterpart”</sub>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford
> Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/) via Google</sub>

You and your “enemies” are all in it together — doing the same things for the same reasons.

Think of it as expanding the idiom *brothers in arms* (same side) to *counterparts in arms* (same war).

Comment: "Counterpart" may be a bit *too* neutral. It doesn't express opposition at all.

Comment: Definitely non-combative, though.

Comment: @NotThatGuy — The prefix *counter-* very much carries the sense of opposition: From the *OED*: **counter-**, *prefix* **2. g. (a)** Forming the opposite member or constituent of anything that has naturally two opposite parts, as COUNTERBALANCE *n.*, COUNTERFOIL *n.*, COUNTERPART *n.*, COUNTERPOISE *n.*, COUNTERSTOCK n., COUNTERTALLY *n.*, etc...

Comment: I was going to suggest either 'adversary', 'opponent' or this, in increasing order of neutrality and nonjudgmentalosity.

Comment: Counterpart suggests cooperation between the parties, so this would not fit.

Comment: No, there is no sense of *cooperation* involved in the word.

Comment: @TinfoilHat strongly disagree. It connotes two parts working opposite of each other to reach a common goal. Like balancing weights on a scale.

Comment: @PCLuddite — There is nothing of “reaching a common goal” in the word *counterpart*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat correct, it may not literally be part  of the definition, but it does have that connotation. Words often carry more meaning than what's at face value.

Comment: @TinfoilHat see [here](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/counterpart) for a full sense of the word. "equivalent" is a synonym of "counterpart", which implies there is more to the definition of "facing against". Your own definition uses "corresponding" which has a communal sense.

Comment: @PCLuddite — What is it that makes you think *equivalent* means “reaching a common goal”?

Comment: @TinfoilHat if something is described as equivalent, that necessarily implies that it accomplishes the same task, and therefore, works toward the same goal. But none of this is really worth arguing at this point.

Answer (score 8):

The adversaries - Collins Concise English Dictionary.

Or the opposition - the same source.

"I was in the British army against the adversaries/opposition for several years".

Answer (score 5):

A bit tongue-in-cheek but they were the **Home Team**

> A team which is playing on its own ground

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/home-team

---

It is sincerely admirable that you are reflecting on yourself and are clearing up your lexicon but if you're re-telling a story then you refer to them by how you knew them in relation to the justification of your actions. As long as you omit slurs then your words/actions will maintain respect.

Simply put, they were the enemy. You wouldn't swap that out with "defendants" unless you wish to demonize your own self. A less harsh connotation is opponent or opposition just as it is an accepted term in game and sports contests.

Don't beat yourself up too much, enemy is fairly neutral as it is. To me it doesn't convey hostility you feel but rather precautions you take when engaging with them. There are plenty of enemy politicians who still shake hands.

Answer (score 5):

**antagonists** is another approximate synonym for "opponents", "adversaries", more neutral than 'enemies'.

from [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/antagonist),

> a person who is opposed to, struggles against, or competes with another; opponent; adversary.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest the word “**rival**”:

From the [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rival):

> a: one of two or more striving to reach or obtain something that only
> one can possess

> b: one striving for competitive advantage

The benefit of this term is that “rivals" are generally considered “equals” which, I believe, confers the dignity that you are looking to achieve.

It also maintains the competitive nature of battle within the word itself, so as to minimize the need for extra words like one might need with other options:

1. ***I came face-to-face with our rivals.***
2. (Instead of) ***I came face-to-face with:***

   - *our equals on the battlefield.*
   - *our counterparts on the other side.*
   - *our peers from the native forces.*

If you don’t mind using a few extra words when necessary, then I believe “**equal**” and “**peer**” might also work nicely for your purposes - as well as “**[counterpart](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609521/368294)**” and “**[the other side](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609515/368294)**”, as @Tinfoil-Hat and @fev have already suggested, respectively.

Comment: There is a difference between competition and direct violence.  "rivals" compete for some zero-sum resource or simply prestige, but don't necessarily take any direct action to hurt each other (and it may be frowned upon — "foul", "unfair competition" etc.).  If you beat my world record, the only way I'm hurt is I'm now 2nd place.  In war OTOH, inflicting damage is a central part of the objectives.

Answer (score 2):

Opposing forces? "Oppose" is a relatively non-volatile word, I feel, but it definitely conveys the necessary information to anyone hearing or reading it, regarding where everybody "stands" in the disagreement/battle/war.
I haven't noticed it being an especially triggering word for anyone.

[Adversary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/adversary) may also be fitting for your situation, but I feel it has a tad bit more sharpness to it!

Cambridge gives:

> an enemy:
> He saw her as his main adversary within the company.

This may seem a bit odd, but I was just doing a little studying on the Law of Polarity, and obviously duality...this is so close to that subject, but I can't quite "pull anything out of the ha"currently! Perhaps you may be inspired by reading a bit about the Law of Polarity, just a thought!!
Have a good one!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

`Opposition`

In as much as combat is a continuation of politics by physical means.

The forces poosing you and your mission are your opposition.

Answer (score 1):

One term that has not been mentioned is [beligerent(s)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belligerent):

> : waging war

> specifically : belonging to or recognized as a state at
> war and protected by and subject to the laws of war

This has a negative connotation in some circumstances (mostly when functioning as an adjective) but is the neutral and [internationally accepted term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belligerent#Belligerency) when referring to the nations or other militant groups engaged in warfare.

Pros of this term:

- Refers to *all* combative parties (e.g. both the USA and Afghanistan are both beligerents in that war)
- Internationally recognized
- Neutral connotation

Cons:

- Potential for this to be conflated with the more recent colloquial definition of "inclined to or exhibiting assertiveness, hostility, or combativeness" and therefore misconstrued
- The older definition is fossilized as a legal one, so using it may come across as somewhat academic and non-colloquial.

Answer (score 0):

*Challenger* can work well to give a chivalrous tone to the enemy, whereby the provocation and the fight are viewed through physical, sporting perspective rather than one of justice. You can also say *battlefield contestant* and *contesting/challenging party*.

Answer (score -4):

"**interlocutor**". I'd justify the suggestion on the following grounds: You're negotiating over territory on behalf of your Nation state. Sure, not in the way we'd usually think about for business negotiations, but at the start of any business negotiation it's not clear if both parties are genuinely working towards the same goal.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interlocutor

Personally, it also conjures the idea of animals locking horns and competing for a mate, but they aren't enemies in the moral sense, just adversaries.

-Edited to clarify post feedback.

Comment: The linked definition is "someone who is involved in a conversation and who is representing someone else" doesn't necessarily suggest an opponent or enemy.

Comment: "interlocutor" doesn't suggest antagonism to me at all ...

Comment: This would almost sound like a facetious or even patronizing euphemism. It's almost like calling yourself and your enemy combatants "diplomats" or "negotiators".